# Java manage a process that doesn't exit automatically

Tags: java

I've a no gui program similar at `su` that works like the figure and I want to manage it with Java `Runtime` to read its exit code.

[image]

To read its exit code I would like close the program soon as possible but I can't wait for process finish because if the machine is supported the process doesn't finish while I send an "exit" command. And I can't send an "exit" string because I don't know how many seconds it works and I don't know if the machine is supported.

If I launch the program in terminal, I can see that while it "works some seconds" I've only the still cursor, if the machine is supported it enters in a sub-shell and change the shell header otherwise it exit and the shell header doesn't change.

Can I read these 3 steps in java? Which is the best way to manage a process like this?

Comment: Yes why not? Have you tried that?

Comment: I've tried with getInputStream() but it return only the process output, not the termianal header, and the process has not output. Is there another way?

Comment: @Andrea993 As far as I know, pipes (`getInputStream()`, etc.) are the only way, unless the process you are talking about was _specifically_ made to work with your Java program.

Comment: Is there any kind of "test"-command you could send the process? If you know the response you should get, you could compare it to the actual response. If you don't get a response or get an Exception, it would be unsupported.

Comment: No, the only way to know if the machine is supported is see if the process exit or open the sub-shell